# Две очереди с ожиданием

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Пытаюсь реализовать очередь (например, в какую-либо кассу) через односвязный список. Время прихода клиентов и время обработки запроса рандомится, т.е. оно совершенно случайное на каком-то промежутке времени.
Вопрос: как сделать обработку клиентов от времени? Чтобы как только касса была свободна, первый элемент списка удалялся и ставился на обработку. Пытался найти везде примеры моделей работы касс в реальном времени, ничего не нашел.
По сути пока что я попытался сделать две очереди из которых "если вошел - уже не вышел", поэтому реализованы только функции удаления с начала списка и добавление в конец

И две кассы: обе работают по-разному, поэтому и для каждого потока - своя функция Job, выполняющая работу.

Программа запускается, но вот функции Job1 и Job2 не работают, ибо значение GetSize() остается равным 0, несмотря на то, что список постепенно заполняется значениями. Как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

std::condition_variable cv;
mutex mtx;
double arrival_time = 0 ;

class List {
  public:
    List();
    ~List();

    void pop_front();
    void push_back(int data);
    int getNum ();
    void clear();
    int GetSize() {return Size;};
  private:
    class Node {
      public:
        Node* pNext;
        int data;
        Node(int data = 0, Node *pNext = nullptr) {
          this->data = data;
          this->pNext = pNext;
        }
    };
      int Size;
      Node *head;
};

List::List(){
  Size = 0;
  head = nullptr;
}

List::~List() {
  clear();
}

int List::getNum(){
  int num = head->data;
  return num;
}

void List::pop_front() {
  if (head) {
  Node *temp = head;
  head = head->pNext;
  delete temp;
  Size--;
}
}

void List::push_back(int data) {
  if (head == nullptr) {
    head = new Node (data);
  }
  else {
    Node *current = this->head;

    while (current->pNext != nullptr) {
      current = current->pNext;
    }
    current->pNext = new Node (data);
  }

  Size++;
}

void List::clear() {
  while (Size) {
    pop_front();
  }
}

double uniform(double min, double max)
{
    return (double)(rand())/RAND_MAX*(max - min) + min;
}

/*void Job1 (List z1, double arr_time1) {
  mtx.lock();
  t1 = arr_time1;
  while (z1.GetSize()!=0) {
  printf("В момент времени %.3f транзакт %d встал на выполнение ", t1, z1.getNum());
  double worktime_1 = uniform(6, 26);
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(worktime_1));
    double donetime_1 = t1 + worktime_1;
    printf("В момент времени %.3f транзакт %d обработан ", donetime_1, z1.getNum());
    t1 = donetime_1;
    z1.pop_front();
  }
  mtx.unlock();
}*/

void Job1 (List z1, double arr_time1) {
  double t1 = arr_time1;
  mtx.lock();
  while (arrival_time < 3600) {
    double worktime_1 = uniform(6, 26);

    while (z1.GetSize()==0)
      this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(1));
    t1 = arrival_time;
    printf("В момент времени %.3f транзакт %d встал на выполнение \n", t1, z1.getNum());
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(worktime_1));
    double donetime_1 = t1 + worktime_1;
    printf("В момент времени %.3f транзакт %d обработан \n", donetime_1, z1.getNum());
    z1.pop_front();
    t1 = donetime_1;
  }
  mtx.unlock();
}

void Job2 (List z2, double arr_time2) {
  double t2 = arr_time2;
  mtx.lock();
  while (arrival_time < 3600) {
    double worktime_2 = uniform(9, 26);

    while (z2.GetSize()==0)
      this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(1));
    t2 = arrival_time;
    printf("В момент времени %.3f транзакт %d встал на выполнение \n", t2, z2.getNum());
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(worktime_2));
    double donetime_2 = t2 + worktime_2;
    printf("В момент времени %.3f транзакт %d обработан \n", donetime_2, z2.getNum());
    z2.pop_front();
    t2 = donetime_2;
  }
  mtx.unlock();
}


int main () {
  List q1, q2;
  srand((unsigned int)time(0));
  thread th1(Job1, q1, arrival_time);
  thread th2(Job2, q2, arrival_time);
  int counter = 1;

  while (arrival_time < 3600) {
    double time = uniform(0,26);
    arrival_time = arrival_time + time;
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>(time));
    printf("В момент времени %.3f транзакт %d встал в очередь ", arrival_time, counter);

    if (q2.GetSize() < q1.GetSize()){
      q2.push_back(counter);
      cout << "2" << endl;

    }
    else {
      q1.push_back(counter);
      cout << "1" << endl;
      //thread th1(Job1, q1, arrival_time);
      //th1.join();
    }
    counter++;
  }
  q1.clear();
  q2.clear();
  th1.join();
  th2.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы один и тот же мутекс mtx лочите в начале каждого job и разблокируете только при его завершении ? У вас же один из потоков из за него будет вечно блокирован. (хотя это так, не работает вообще думаю по другой причине)

Comment: спасибо, сделал два разных мутекса. но ведь метод getsize() все равно остается равным 0. не подскажете, как сделать ожидание, если элементов в очереди 0, но нужно подождать, когда их будет 1 и больше, чтобы обрабатывать дальше?